# Alamofire - Not accepting error in a failureCallBack

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

We are using the Alamofire pod. Now I'm facing an issue with NSError.

When we write `error: responseObj.result.error`, Swift 3 is not accepting this. Help me to solve this problem.

Check my code:

```
static func getDataFromAPI(parameters : [String : AnyObject], successCallBack : @escaping APISuccessCallBack, failureCallBack : @escaping APIFailureCallBack) {

    client.makePOSTRequest(service: Constants.API_BASE_URL, parameters: parameters) { (statusCode, response, error) -> () in

        if statusCode == MobomoAPIClient.HTTPStatusCode.Success {
            successCallBack(response)
        }
        else {
            failureCallBack(client.responseErrorMessage(statusCode: statusCode, response: response, error: error!))
        }
    }
}

typealias APIClientResponseCallBack = (_ statusCode: Int?, _ response : AnyObject?, _ error : Error?) -> ()

func makePOSTRequest (service : String!, parameters : [String: AnyObject]? = nil,  responseCallBack : APIClientResponseCallBack!) {
    self.sendRequest(method: .post, service: service, parameters: parameters, responseCallBack: responseCallBack);
}

private func sendRequest (method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod, service : String!, parameters : [String: AnyObject]? = nil, responseCallBack : APIClientResponseCallBack!) {

    var headers : [String : String] = [String : String]()
    headers["Accept-Version"] = "1.0"
    var urlString = self.urlStringWithService(service: service)
    urlString = Constants.API_BASE_URL

    self.alamoFireManager!.request(urlString, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { (responseObj) -> Void in
            responseCallBack(statusCode: responseObj.response?.statusCode, response: responseObj.result.value as AnyObject, error: responseObj.result.error)
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of status code response did you receive?

Comment: cannot invoke 'responseCallBack' with argument list of type '(statusCode: Int?, response : AnyObject?, error : Error?)' facing this issue

Comment: if you print `responseObj.response` you will see the response status code.

Comment: all the code working correctly but last parameter (error) not accepting a any type of value. i want to pass responseObj.result.error this value but error occured. help me to pas the value to last parameter (error)

Comment: what did you write on `APIClientResponseCallBack ` ?

Comment: to get a api's  response that why I'm use APIClientResponseCallBack

Comment: Well, maybe the `APIClientResponseCallBack ` has error parameter as NSError, you'll need to change it to Error.

Comment: already we change NSError to Error.

Comment: mmmmm... so what kind of error did you receive from xCode?

Comment: cannot invoke 'responseCallBack' with argument list of type '(statusCode: Int?, response : AnyObject?, error : Error?)' facing this issue

Comment: Well I'm thinking the error is `responseObj.error` 'cos this is a response from callBack

Answer (score 0):

```
responseCallBack(responseObj.response?.statusCode, responseObj.result.value as AnyObject, responseObj.result.error)
```

this work for me